# Invalid input focus is not working with FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So everything works fine with normal FormGroup but when it comes to FormArray it doesn't focus the invalid input.

My form initialization is below

```
initForm() {
    this.parentForm= this.fb.group({
      childFormArray: this.fb.array([this.createchildForm()])
    });
  }
```

after this, I initialize formarray like below

```
createChildForm(data?: any): FormGroup {
    var childForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [data?.name? data?.name: '']
    });
    childForm .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      var fieldWithValue = Object.keys(value).filter(key => value[key] == '');
      fieldWithValue.forEach(conName => {
         childForm .get(conName)?.addValidators([Validators.required]);
      });
    });
    return childForm ;
  }
```

My method to set errors after clicking submit (requirement);

```
   assignError(){
    this.parentForm.controls.childFormArray.value.forEach((v: any, index: number) => {
          var array = this.parentForm.controls.childFormArrayas FormArray;
          var item = array.at(index);
          var emptyItems = Object.keys(v).filter(key => v[key] == '');
          emptyItems.forEach(ele => {
            if (ele != "section") {
              item.get(ele)?.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
            }
          });
        });
       }
```

and after this I have made my validator which will check for invalid input and focus it.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[focusInvalidInput]'
})
export class FormDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
    @HostListener('submit')
    onFormSubmit() {
        const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
        if (invalidControl) {
            invalidControl.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

after this I have used its selector in my corresponding form

```
focusInvalidInput (ngSubmit)="saveDetails()"
```

and inside submit method I call my error adding method which is

```
 saveDetails(){
  assignError();
}
```

After doing all this I am able to focus invalid input but somehow its not working for formarray.

and when I console invalidControl its prints all the invalid input which should not happen maybe bcz there are many invalid input and whome should it focus so I tried using **.first()** method but it gives error saying **first** is not a method

Comment: I did not get of your this line `name: [data?.name? data?.name: '']`

Comment: Could you create stackblitz?

Comment: @GRD actually it was space issue while writing this question. Actually that is
```name: [data?.name ? data?.name: '']```

Comment: @GRD I have found a solution which I will update in my question

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason was focus doesn't work on div and my input which were using formArray's controls were wrapped inside a div which is

```
<div id="resp-table-body" *ngFor="let item of getParentFormControls(); let i = index"
                            [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="table-body-cell">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control no_shadow_input" id="name"
                                        placeholder="Enter Here" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off">
                                    <span *ngIf="item.get('name')?.hasError('required')"
                                        class="text-danger">
                                        Name is required
                                    </span>
                                </div>
    </div>
```

So all I had to change is add input.ng-invalid in my directive

```
const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input.ng-invalid');
```

Now everything is working fine